# rsync 100 files of size 30GB each from one remote server to an other in parallel

Tags: rsync

I am in need to transfer 100 files of size 30GB each from one remote server to another.

I have saved all the files I want to transfer in a file named `to_transfer`. most of the files are in such format

- 1.dat
- 1.idx
- 1.vif

all the files are in such pair, `n.dat`, `n.idx`, `n.vif`.

I am using this command.

```
rsync -azP --remove-source-files --progress --files-from=/storage/to_transfer /storage root@media.evercam.io:/tmp
```

This transfer the files one by one but I want to move all the files in parallel, I have a guaranteed bandwidth of 1 GBit/s. How I can make the most out of it?

I am deleting the files after full transfer as well.

Comment: I don't know if `rsync` has a "parallel mode", but you could loop over the file and launch background processes: `for f in $(cat to_transfer); do rsync $f ... &; done`. I doubt you gain much by running the copies in parallel, though. It will probably be slower because you will cause erratic disk access on both source and destination, and disk IO will be the bottleneck rather than network capacity.

Comment: Okay but can I utilize the full internet speed even while transferring a single file? one by one?

Comment: I am sure you can. But what prevents you from trying? You could start transferring two or three files in parallel, to get the feeling.

Comment: I think am missing something because I tried one by one transfer and I got 26MB/s speed. I don't know why

Comment: My prediction is that running 100 `rsync`'s in parallel will strain your disk IO system so much that you will get less of that speed. But perhaps you have particularly fast disks, or RAIDs etc. Happy to be proven wrong :)

Comment: I have `256 GB DDR4 ECC`  of ram and  `SATA 6 Gb/s 7200 rpm` hdds. and source server has zfs raid 2z and the destination servr has xfs filesystem and RAID6 adaptec.

Comment: TBH is it worth spending the effort for a five minute transfer window? (It depends on how often you're doing this transfer.)

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit. If you want to ask for clarifications to an answer, do so in comments to the answer. If you want to ask a new question, then open a completely new question.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallelizing-rsync

```
cd src-dir
find . -type f |
  parallel -j10 rsync -zR -Ha ./{} fooserver:/dest-dir/
```

Comment: thank you. but can you explain a bit and use the described parameter? i.e using the list of files?

Comment: can you describe how I can use the file input in this above method?

Comment: Can you explain what `./{}` this means here? and what is -j10?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq (a) The find lists all filenames in the cwd. Substitute that command with `cat to_transfer`. (b) `parallel -j10` runs 10 "jobs" -- each running the following command with one-tenth of the filenames. (c) The `{}` tells parallel where in that command to insert each filename. (d) If your single transfer used a fifth of the bandwidth (1 GBit / 25 MB), then more than ten jobs is probably going to give diminishing returns. The specific man pages give more detail in each case.